# How to save a comma within text into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form where users can save text to a mysql database. I'm using a prepared statement to insert the data but I can't understand why I am unable to insert any text that has a comma. When I retrieve the `$detail` string it echoe's out but ends as soon as it hits a comma. What am I missing? Thanks.

Example: I want to insert this statement, ok.

Prints out: I want to insert this statement

My code (simplified)

```
$detail=htmlentities($_POST["detail"], ENT_QUOTES);
$id=$_POST["id"];

$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_uploads SET detail=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$detail,$id);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->execute()) { //true
    echo'success';
}else{
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: have you checked in db for test if the problem  is in uodated  or in select  ..?

Comment: Have you verified that it's actually wrong in the database, rather than it being a problem when you retrieve it and echo it back out? Oh, I think I'm asking the same thing as @scaisEdge, actually.

Comment: The string is correctly saved into the db so I guess it's just not printing out correctly.

Comment: You can edit the question to include that part if you like. Otherwise I think this isn't really answerable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Indeed, the problem lay with a rather complicated way I was getting at the variable. Working now.